# Center align Labels and images inside UIView programatically with Swift

Tags: ios, uiview, centering

Im working on an app and came across a problem that I cant seem to solve.

I am making a uiview with labels and images inside it. The content needs to be centered inside the view.

The problem is that the label will hold different lenght texts and the view itself will have different width depending on where it is used.

Here is how it should look:

[image]

And here with longer text:

[image]

As you can see there should be 1 label to the left, one uiimage in the middle and another label to the right all centered to the middle even though the text length could be different.

This is what I have so far in code. I need to do this programatically if possible. Im running a method to create the button depending on a value.

```
    func cost(cost:Int){

    costView = UIView()
    costView?.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    self.costView?.clipsToBounds = true
    self.addSubview(costView!)


    self.costLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, self.bounds.size.height)
    self.costLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
    self.costLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.costLabel.font = Services.exoFontWithSize(16)
    self.costLabel.text = String(cost)
    costView?.addSubview(costLabel)



    self.costBrainImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.height, self.bounds.size.height))
    self.costBrainImageView?.image = Graphics.maskImageNamed("CommonMediumBrain", color: UIColor.whiteColor())
    self.costBrainImageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
    costView?.addSubview(costBrainImageView!)




    self.label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    self.label.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    self.label.numberOfLines = 1
    self.label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.20
    self.label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
    self.label.font = Services.exoFontWithSize(20)


    //Constraints
    var viewsDict = Dictionary <String, UIView>()
    viewsDict["label"] = label
    viewsDict["brainView"] = costView


    self.addConstraints(
        NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
            "V:|[label]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
    self.addConstraints(
        NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
            "V:|[brainView]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
    self.addConstraints(
        NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
            "H:|-[label]-5-[brainView]-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))

}
```

For the moment this breaks since this line

```
NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterX
```

'Unable to parse constraint format: 
Options mask required views to be aligned on a horizontal edge, which is not allowed for layout that is also horizontal. 
H:|-[label]-5-[brainView]-|

If i remove that everything is aligned to the left and not centered but im not sure this is the right way to accomplish what i want to do.

Any clues on how to solve this?

Thanks for any help

Comment: I think you need to Fix the width  of your  label and Also your Option should be Nil

Comment: It's not clear to me what in your code corresponds to what in your image. Is the black rounded rectangle costView, or is costView a subview of the black rectangle? I see that you're adding a label and an image view to costView but not the one you call self.label. Why? Which label is self.label? Also, what is "self" in this code?

Comment: @rdelmar The self.view is the actual rounded rectangle (like a superview) it holds some methods for different presentations mainly for just presenting text. costview holds 1 image and 1 label. That was mainly to make it easier to move thos two around and so that I only needed to handle and center two objects, the label and the costview. But maybe that not a good Idea? :S

Comment: I think I would probably not use costView at all, and add the 2 labels and the image view directly to the black rectangle (or put all 3 in costView, if you have some other reason to have it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, change `.AlignAllCenterX` to `.AlignAllCenterY`, the reason is that`"H:|-[label]-5-[brainView]-|"` specifies how views position horizontally, you want `label` and `brainView` to have the same center Y position.

Secondly, make a subview that contains all 3 views, then center this subview inside the black rectangle. You can use `costView` as the subview. 
Below is some modified code based on your existing code.

```
costView!.addSubview(label)

//Constraints
var viewsDict = Dictionary <String, UIView>()
viewsDict["label"] = label
viewsDict["brainView"] = costBrainImageView
viewsDict["costLabel"] = costLabel

costView!.addConstraints(
    NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "V:|[label]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
costView!.addConstraints(
    NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "V:|[brainView]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
costView!.addConstraints(
    NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "V:|[costLabel]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
costView!.addConstraints(
    NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:|-[label]-5-[brainView]-5-[costLabel]-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterY, metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
costView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

// center costView inside self
let centerXCons = NSLayoutConstraint(item: costView!, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0);
let centerYCons = NSLayoutConstraint(item: costView!, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0);
self.addConstraints([centerXCons, centerYCons])
```

Comment: Amazing it works!!! :D Thanks so much @gabbler. I had to add width and height to the image view so that the image dont stretch "V:|[brainView(<=40)]|" but except that it works perfect! Thanks for saving my day!