# Center aligning multiple labels using Swift 3 Xcode 8

Tags: swift, xcode, uilabel

I want to align three labels as a group to center Horizontally. Two of the labels have variable size. I referred to following post thoroughly but my app is crashing with following message:

**POST:**
[Center align Labels and images inside UIView programatically with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29184492/center-align-labels-and-images-inside-uiview-programatically-with-swift)

**Error Message:**

> When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of
>   that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint
>   needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled.

Couple of things:
I already have constraints in Autolayout for these three labels. For "InLabel" I have leading space from margin, width and spacing from top neighbor. For other two labels (durationLable & timeUnitLabel) I have space inbetween all three labels and spacing from top neighbor.

UIView is initialized as indurtimeView = UIView() in the beginning part of class ViewController

I'm calling function indurtimeLabelcenter() in "viewDidLoad" function after calling super.viewDidLoad() in ViewController class.

Here is my code for function indurtimeLabelcenter():

```
func indurtimeLabelcenter() {
    //Align "In", "Duration Lable" and "Time Unit Label" to center
    self.view.addSubview(indurtimeView)
    indurtimeView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    indurtimeView.clipsToBounds = true
    indurtimeView.addSubview(InLabel)

    //Constraints
    var viewsDict = Dictionary <String, UIView>()
    viewsDict["InLabel"] = InLabel
    viewsDict["durationLabel"] = durationLabel
    viewsDict["timeunitLabel"] = timeUnitLabel

    indurtimeView.addConstraints(
        NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
            withVisualFormat: "V:|[InLabel]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
    indurtimeView.addConstraints(
        NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
            withVisualFormat: "V:|[durationLabel]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
    indurtimeView.addConstraints(
        NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
            withVisualFormat: "V:|[timeunitLabell]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
    indurtimeView.addConstraints(
        NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
            withVisualFormat: "H:|-[InLabel]-5-[durationLabel]-5-[timeunitLabel]-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.alignAllCenterY, metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
    //costView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    // center costView inside self
    let centerXCons = NSLayoutConstraint(item: indurtimeView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0);
    let centerYCons = NSLayoutConstraint(item: indurtimeView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0);
    self.view.addConstraints([centerXCons, centerYCons])
}
```

First time writing App in Swift so bear with my ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, it seems you may have an error in the following line:

```
var viewsDict = Dictionary <String, UIView>()
```

I believe you meant to make your dictionary value type `UILabel`. However, you have it as type `UIView`. The only change would be:

```
var viewsDict = Dictionary <String, UILabel>()
```

In either case though, to answer your question, you can center align multiple labels in a dictionary by doing the following:

```
var viewsDict = Dictionary <String, UILabel>()
viewsDict["InLabel"] = InLabel
viewsDict["durationLabel"] = durationLabel
viewsDict["timeunitLabel"] = timeUnitLabel

for label in viewsDict.values {
    label.center.x = view.bounds.width/2
}
```

This loops over the dictionary values, assigning the center x value of each `UILabel` to the center of the screen.

**Update**
Calculates manually but if you cannot get your constraints to work, can always do it this way.

```
let labelOneXOrigin = screenWidth-10-labelOne.frame.width-labelTwo.frame.width-labelThree.frame.width
let labelTwoXOrigin = labelOne.frame.origin.x+labelOne.frame.width+5
let labelThreeXOrigin = labelTwo.frame.origin.x+labelTwo.frame.width+5
```

Comment: May be I didn't make myself clear. All labels are on the same line and I want to align all of them as a group to the center. Dictionary is of type UIView because I'm adding sub views to it.

Comment: I think I get what you're asking now, for clarification though by "on the same line", do you mean each are directly next to each other with no space in between?

Comment: There is a space of constant value 5 between those lables.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Finally ... I figured it out. There were a couple of issues. Firstly, I was adding subview only for one label. It has to be added for all three labels (Which needs to be aligned in center together). Secondly, since I wanted to align them in center horizontally, I don't need to provide "centerYcons". Thirdly, one of the label had a constraint of constant space from left margin. It needs to be removed because it can't satisfy constraints of both centering it and also constant space from left margin. I've provided working code below:

```
func indurtimeLabelcenter() {
    //Align "In", "Duration Lable" and "Time Unit Label" to center
    self.view.addSubview(indurtimeView)
    indurtimeView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    indurtimeView.addSubview(InLabel)
    indurtimeView.addSubview(durationLabel)
    indurtimeView.addSubview(timeUnitLabel)

    //Constraints
    var viewsDict = Dictionary <String, UIView>()
    viewsDict["InLabel"] = InLabel
    viewsDict["durationLabel"] = durationLabel
    viewsDict["timeunitLabel"] = timeUnitLabel

    indurtimeView.addConstraints(
        NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
            withVisualFormat: "V:|[InLabel]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
    indurtimeView.addConstraints(
        NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
            withVisualFormat: "V:|[durationLabel]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
    indurtimeView.addConstraints(
        NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
            withVisualFormat: "V:|[timeunitLabel]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
    indurtimeView.addConstraints(
        NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
            withVisualFormat: "H:|-[InLabel]-5-[durationLabel]-5-[timeunitLabel]-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.alignAllCenterY, metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))

    // center costView inside self
    let centerXCons = NSLayoutConstraint(item: indurtimeView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0);
    //let centerYCons = NSLayoutConstraint(item: indurtimeView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0);
    self.view.addConstraints([centerXCons])
}
```